# How to know the number of non-zero elements of a Fortran array?

Tags: arrays, fortran, size

So I have something like this:

```
INTEGER i
REAL value(10)

DO i = 1,5 
  value(i) = 1
ENDDO
```

So now my value = (1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0).
What would be the function that gives size = 5 (the size of the array without the zeros)?

Comment: Please, it was quite unclear. The size of an array is always 10. If you mean size of a continuous part until the first zero than please say that explixitly.

Answer (score 8):

Just count the non-zero elements

```
print *, count(value/=0)
```

Comment: even better! Thanks!